# Two view controllers (with nibs) acting on the screen at the same time

Tags: objective-c, xcode, delegates, viewcontroller

Just as a disclaimer, I am an iOS beginner, in a pretty unique position. I'm an intern learning on the job, with a hard deadline for a test app, with specific specs. So I unfortunately don't have the luxury of learning all that I should about xCode and objective C.

Anyways, I am trying to create a navigation menu similar to the iPad's slide out menu. I've looked at plenty of sample code given in response to questions like this in the past. It all works perfectly fine, but I can't understand all of what they're doing. I think this results from being fairly bewildered by view controllers and delegates. And, since I'm supposed to be writing this all by myself, I can't just build off of their existing code.

My plan for this working is to have one main view controller, containing the navigation menu in a table view. This is hidden behind a normal UIView, until a button is pressed, at which point the normal UIView slides offscreen enough to reveal the menu. Upon selection of a menu item, the normal UIView would slide back to its original position, and be replaced by the relevant UIView, controlled by its view controller. In other words, clicking on the menu item relating to "Home" would load the homeViewController.xib, controlled by the homeViewController. This would be loaded in that normal UIView subview, on top of the tableView.

I'm able to load a view in that normal UIView as a result of a button press.

```
homeViewController *_homeViewController = [[homeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"homeViewController"];
[self frontView] = _homeViewController.view;
```

There may be some syntax errors in that code, since its from memory. I'm not able to access the computer with my code on it at the moment, but that's the general gist. Basically, that places the home view nib on the frontView (that normal UIView that's over the table view), but its not connected to homeViewController. Or at least I think that's the issue, when I press a button, that's correctly connected between the nib and the homeViewController.h, and only set to NSLog in the .m file, the application crashes.

Any idea how to connect this nib to its viewController when displayed in this way? Or, to create the nib in IB, without the associated .h and .m files, and use the main view controller as the homeViewController as well? Or, if my logic is inherently flawed, what SHOULD I do? Something with NavigationControllers?

EDIT:
I also tried a new approach- changing homeViewController's file owner to viewController, and connecting the button on homeViewController's action to viewController. This too caused a crash upon pressing the button. I really think the issue is with having multiple view controllers acting on screen at once, or having multiple views from separate nibs, controlled by one view controller on screen at once.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your immediate problem is that `_homeViewController` is being freed as soon as you leave whatever method that code is in.  To fix this, create a `strong` property in this class that holds the `_homeViewController` for as long as its view is needed and allocate it to that property rather than a local variable.  That way, buttons (or whatever) that are part of that view still have a valid controller object backing them.

In the long run, pushing or presenting view controllers when you need the screen to change is a **much** better strategy but, as I said, the immediate problem....  :)

Comment: When I try that, I'm getting two errors: Property with retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type, and Interface type cannot be statically allocated. Just to clarify, you are suggesting putting the property in the viewController.h, right? Also, wouldn't pushing remove the tableView underneath? And presenting doesn't work, as I don't necessarily want to return to the same view as before, correct?

Comment: Yes, in the .h file.  The second error message sounds as if you forgot a `*` and tried to declare something like `homeViewController controller;`.  I'm not sure about the first but perhaps a missing `@class homeViewController;`.  If those guesses don't work, you could add the new code to your question and I'll have a look at it.

Comment: I really think we're going down the wrong path here, as continued attempts to approach this problem from different angles (outlined in the edit to my main post) lead to the same result. I really think there's some fundamental disconnect between how I imagine views and view controllers interacting, and how they actually do. Or perhaps the fact that delegates confuse me to no end.

Comment: Possibly.  It would certainly be easier to diagnose with real error messages.  If you put the code that fails inside a @try/@catch and log the exception's `description` and `callStackSymbols`, that might tell you something useful.  Another approach would be using the "Product->Profile" menu and checking for zombies with it.